# JavaScript: Insert variable into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I am customising a plugin that has array (if that is what is it) that holds config items:

```
        var config = {
            width:  "100%",
            height: "100%",
            source: 'js/timeline/test.json',                
            css:    'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css',    
            js:     'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js'   
        }
```

What I want to do is take the `source:` data and replace it with a variable eg:

```
var mysource = 'path/to/source.json';

var config = {
                width:  "100%",
                height: "100%",
                source: mysource ,              
                css:    'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css',    
                js:     'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js'   
            }
```

But as it above it does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

EDIT: Added full code as requested

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/json.php',

    function(data) {

        jsonObject = eval(data);
        var eventdata = jsonObject.tlall;

    });

}); //END ON LOAD

var config = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    source: eventdata,
    //source: 'js/timeline/test.json',
    //start_at_end: true,   //OPTIONAL              
    //hash_bookmark: true,  //OPTIONAL              
    css: 'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css',
    js: 'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js'
}​
```

Comment: Is it because you have 2 commas on the line before?

Comment: @nbrooks sorry guys - that was a mistake when I was transcribing the code. The problem still remains

Comment: I don't see any problem! Do you have them in same block/function ?

Comment: how do you "re-init" the plugin to use your customised config?

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: mysource is not defined"

Comment: @MeltingDog please share the full code, it sounds as if they are not being defined within the same scope

Comment: Seems to work just fine [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v7VYk/), are you declaring the `mysource` variable in the right scope.

Comment: @nbrooks ok I have added the full code above

Comment: That's not an array btw, it's an object, or list of key:value pairs. Similar to a dictionary in other languages. Somtimes referred to as a hash or map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you plan to use `config`, but you certainly need it to be within the same scope in order to access `eventdata`. I would say get rid of that altogether, and just add it as a property of the object in the ajax callback (shown in code below).

The difficulty here is that you are stuck waiting on the AJAX callback to fire before you can use `config` in your scripts; this is why ajax is designed to be used with callbacks executed after a particular event rather than linearly; I would advise you to use `config` only within that success callback, or add a check to see if `getJSON` has finished executing.

```
$(function() {

    var config = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",            
        css: 'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css',
        js: 'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js'
    };

    $.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/json.php', function(data) {
        jsonObject = eval(data);
        config.source = jsonObject.tlall;
    });

}); //END ON LOAD​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks! This has gotten rid of my Uncaught Reference Error

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
var eventdata = jsonObject.tlall;
```

To this:

```
config.source = jsonObject.tlall;
```

And remove this line from your config definition:

```
source: eventdata,
```

Answer (score 1):

Scoping issue, try :

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/json.php', function(data) {
        config.source = data.tlall;
    });

    var config = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        css: 'js/timeline/compiled/css/timeline.css',
        js: 'js/timeline/compiled/js/timeline-min.js'
    }
});​
​
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work, due to the fact that eventdata is only assigned once the AJAX call returns.